# jQuery $.post - do I have to encode the URL parameter?

Tags: url, jquery

I'm making an AJAX call with `$.post(url, cb)`. The URL I'm passing in could potentially have weird characters like spaces, `&`, `?` and so on.

Do I have to use `$.post(encodeURIComponent(url), cb)`?

`url` is something like `/foo/weird-char§`.

Comment: As far as i know, not for POST no.

Comment: that is pointless because I can make a form from my localhost to post to your forms `action` attribute (url) and escape the `encodeURIComponent` should use the server side to take care of that to be 100% sure

Comment: @Val this is not about security, but about properly sending the request

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Do I have to use $.post(encodeURIComponent(url), cb)?

You *will* have to use `encodeURIComponent()` but *not* on the entire URI, only on the data part (`weird` and `chars` in your example). The URL and the `? &` separating the parameters must stay intact. If you encode the entire URI, it will become unusable.

If you would add the data as POST data using the `data` parameter:

```
url = "/foo/possible";
$.post(url, { "weird": "f2(90§§$", "chars": "ß1028490" });
```

jQuery's Ajax functions would take care of URL encoding the data automatically.

Comment: I was planning to try to escape the ? and & chars, but I see that's not really a good plan. What if it weren't /foo/possible, but rather /foo/po§§ible?

Comment: nornagon then you will indeed need to escape `po§§ible`, but you mustn't escape the slashes `/`

Comment: This exactly what I'm doing: `$.post(url, { param1: "normalText", param2: "contains %" });`, but the **param2** is not being properly decoded in the server because it's not properly encoded by jQuery.

Comment: @Gustavo weird! Pretty sure jQuery is supposed to do the encoding in that case but can't quickly find a source for it. What does the value look like in the request?

Comment: Nevermind, it was a caching issue. After I changed from `$.ajax` to `$.post` and properly passed the data as a PlainObject not as String, the encoding worked.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to encode the keys and values in the query string (but not the `?` which separates the path from the query arguments and the `&` which separates the query arguments).  This is built into jQuery if you use the data parameter of the `$.post`, like so:

```
$.post(url, { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, cb);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MVC3/EntityFramework as back-end, the front-end consumes all of my project controllers via jquery, posting directly (using $.post) doesnt requires the data encription, when you pass params directly other than URL hardcoded.
I already tested several chars i even sent an URL(this one http://www.ihackforfun.eu/index.php?title=update-on-url-crazy&more=1&c=1&tb=1&pb=1) as a parameter and had no issue at all even though encodeURIComponent works great when you pass all data in within the URL (hardcoded)

Hardcoded URL i.e.>

```
 var encodedName = encodeURIComponent(name);
 var url = "ControllerName/ActionName/" + encodedName + "/" + keyword + "/" + description + "/" + linkUrl + "/" + includeMetrics + "/" + typeTask + "/" + project + "/" + userCreated + "/" + userModified + "/" + status + "/" + parent;; // + name + "/" + keyword + "/" + description + "/" + linkUrl + "/" + includeMetrics + "/" + typeTask + "/" + project + "/" + userCreated + "/" + userModified + "/" + status + "/" + parent;
```

Otherwise dont use encodeURIComponent and instead try passing params in within the ajax post method

```
 var url = "ControllerName/ActionName/";   
 $.post(url,
        { name: nameVal, fkKeyword: keyword, description: descriptionVal, linkUrl: linkUrlVal, includeMetrics: includeMetricsVal, FKTypeTask: typeTask, FKProject: project, FKUserCreated: userCreated, FKUserModified: userModified, FKStatus: status, FKParent: parent },
 function (data) {.......});
```